# Can we model the pitch up of an aircraft due to sudden application of brakes while it is rolling down an inclined using angular impulse method?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, rotational-dynamics, torque, models

Consider an aircraft parked on an inclined plane. Due to a mistake by the pilot the brakes were released, and the wheel chocks were missing. When the plane started to roll down, the pilot applied the brakes suddenly.
I am trying to calculate the roll down velocity at the time of application of brakes for which the aircraft will start to pitch up. I have thought of a few approach like balancing torque about the center of gravity, and using the impulse of the applied brake force. However, I haven't been able to properly solve it. I am getting confused on how to write the equations.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can. Apply an impulse at tire contact to stop the motion and measure the angular impulse about the center of mass to figure out how rotational motion changes.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are missing is the suspension.  You wont get an intuitive answer without it, because the suspension is a driving part of the story.

Without a suspension, you apply the breaks, which results in a static force that we can think of as a torque around the wheels.  So long as this torque is less than the torque around the wheels caused by gravity, the plane will stay on the ground.  The instant this is no longer true, the plane's front wheel will leave the ground.  This will continue until the velocity slows, which decreases the torque the wheels can apply.

However, in practice the plane is on a suspension.  When you hit the brakes, there will be joints that move, changing how the torque is applied to the plane.  In general, the force will be applied with ramp up, which means the plane will be able to stay on its wheels longer.